# Specified cast is not valid exception

Tags: c#, casting, datatable

This is my code

```
var result = (from row1 in table.AsEnumerable()
                          join row2 in tabelPopup.AsEnumerable()
                          on row1.Field<string>("CallID") equals
                          row2.Field<string>("callID")
                          where row1.Field<string>("Direction") == "I"
                          select new
                          {
                              Agent = row1.Field<string>("Agent"),
                              StartTime = row1.Field<DateTime>("StartTime"),
                              Reason = row2.Field<string>("Reason")
                          });
```

where `table` and `tablePopup` are datatable variables.

I got this exception:

```
Specified cast is not valid
```

on this code:

```
 new
                          {
                              Agent = row1.Field<string>("Agent"),
                              StartTime = row1.Field<DateTime>("StartTime"),
                              Reason = row2.Field<string>("Reason")
                          }
```

Comment: Are you sure the column definitions are correct? i.e Agent is string, StartTime is datetime and Reason is string?

Comment: Obviously, one of the fields contains the value of a type, which isn't expected by `Field<T>` method (assume, that all it does is `(T)row[fieldName]`).

Comment: @artm you right, `datetime` should be `string`, type an answer to accept it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your column definitions match the type you're using in row1.field<>. i.e. Agent is string, StartTime is datetime and Reason is string. This is likely due to StartTime not being a datetime type.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `StartTime` is not from Type `DateTime`. Because of that you receive this exception. Try to convert it. If this is correct you should convert it to `DateTime` or just retrieve string value.

Comment: +1 to you, but `artm` found the solution before you so forgive me please to no accept your answer +1

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli no worries :)